# How to get the Max Date, Min Date and Null is the column is empty using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some trouble in creating an SQL query. I want query the records in my table with all columns and rows.

I use the below `select` query. It actually reflects the records that I want, but the only problem is it only shows 3 column out of the 19 column. It only shows the column of `Barangay`, `Wentoff` and `Restored`. What I want is to show all the 19 columns of the corresponding result.

This is my SQL Code:

```
SELECT Barangay, MIN(wentoff) as Wentoff, 
CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Restored IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN MAX(Restored) End 
FROM ReportforValidation 
GROUP BY Barangay
```

Please see the current result of my query:

[image: This is the result of the query]

The fields of the the table that I need to show:

[image: The field of the the table that need to show]

Comment: Please do not add output or error-messages as images. They are a pain to read. Edit your question to add any additional information as text. And reduce your heading as proper formatted text.

Comment: *"the only problem is it only shows only 3 Row"*: how many rows did you expect to get?

Comment: I have 19 rows. if possible to show it all

Comment: You are confusing the terms "rows" and "columns". You probably want all columns for the three rows. What is the DBMS you are using? Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Oracle or PostgreSQL? With SQL questions this is important to know.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sir want to reflect the entire rows of the 3 column result. Im using SQL Server sir

Comment: Okay, so I was right. Not "all rows", but "all columns". And your DBMS is ___? And you want one result row per `Bangaray`?

Comment: Im using SQL Server sir this is the code i use to query my result " SELECT Barangay, MIN(wentoff) as Wentoff, CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Restored IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN MAX(Restored) End FROM ReportforValidation GROUP BY Barangay "    the only problem with this code is it only appears the 3 rows out of my 19 rows.

Comment: You are still saying rows. Do you mean rows? You want 19 rows? Not 3 rows with 19 columns? Again: Do you want one result row per Barangay? Yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions instead of `group by`:

```
SELECT  Barangay, 
        MIN(wentoff) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Barangay
        ) as Wentoff, 
        FIRST_VALUE(Restored) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Barangay 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN Restored IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
                     Restored DESC
        ),
        ReportNo,
        area,
        calamaty,
        response
FROM    ReportforValidation;
```

Add all the columns you want to have in the output to the `select` clause.

If you don't want *all* the rows, but only those that have the "first value" of `Restored`, then also select the partition's row number and wrap that in a `select` query that filters for row number 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
    SELECT  Barangay, 
            MIN(wentoff) OVER (
                PARTITION BY Barangay
            ) as Wentoff, 
            FIRST_VALUE(Restored) OVER (
                PARTITION BY Barangay 
                ORDER BY CASE WHEN Restored IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
                         Restored DESC
            ) Restored,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY Barangay 
                ORDER BY CASE WHEN Restored IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
                         Restored DESC
            ) as rn,
            ReportNo,
            area,
            calamaty,
            response
    FROM    ReportforValidation
    ) as all_rows
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: ok sir i will try it that was quick response thanks much

Comment: sir i try the code you give, it actually show the whole rows.. but the problem is the result is its not correct

Comment: Your question says you want all rows. I have added a query that only shows the 3 rows. Is that what you want?

Comment: i want to show the max date if of the restored if the restored rows is not empty. then if the Restored row is empty then the Minimum date of the Wentoff Rows will appear

Comment: You are using strange terminology. `Restored` is not a row. It is a field.

Comment: ok sir i will correct it a Restored Field i mean and a Wentoff Field

Comment: To avoid a long discussion here, can you help us all and edit your question and provide the *data* in your table (a sample) and the *expected output* of the query? That will resolve any misunderstanding.

Comment: ok sir copy thank you so much.. this is my final question sir I will modify my terminology. I want to show the max date of the restored Field if the restored Field is not empty. then if the Restored Field is empty then the Minimum date of the Wentoff Field will appear.

Comment: my bad sir im confuse of column and rows.

Comment: ok sir copy thank you so much.. this is my final question sir I will modify my terminology. I want to show the max date of the restored Field if the restored Field is not empty. then if the Restored Field is empty then the Minimum date of the Wentoff Field will appear.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the **data** in your table (a sample of it) and the **expected** output of the query for that data?

Comment: Hmmm... apparently you are not going to do that. In that case I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@trincot sir your codes works perfectly my only concern with this code is that the rn is also appearing in the column. how can i hide it?
SELECT *
FROM   (
SELECT  Barangay,
MIN(wentoff) OVER (
PARTITION BY Barangay
) as Wentoff,
FIRST_VALUE(Restored) OVER (
PARTITION BY Barangay
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Restored IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
Restored DESC
) Restored,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
PARTITION BY Barangay
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Restored IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
Restored DESC
) as rn,
ReportNo,
area,
calamaty,
response
FROM    ReportforValidation
) as all_rows
WHERE rn = 1;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).